# Proving energy conservation for wave equation

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Hi guys I have a midterm tommorow and I was doing this practice problem that I need help on.

So any hints or solutions would be appreciated. Thank you for your time

**Problem**

The head of timpani is constituted by some kind of elastic membrane which is stretched over a circular bowl; in a mathematical language, we are studying the displacement $u$ of the membrane as a function $u(x, y, t)$ deﬁned in $D = \{(x,y,t) \ |\ x^2 + y^2 \leq R, \ -\infty < t < \infty\}$, where $R$ is the radius of the bowl. The function u satisﬁes the two-dimensional Wave Equation

$u_{tt} = c^2(u_{xx} + u_{yy})$

with Dirichlet boundary conditions $u = 0$ on the boundary. Prove conservation of energy E(t), which is deﬁned as

$E(t) = \frac{1}{2} \iint\limits_D u_{t}^2 + c^2 (u_{x}^2 + u_{y}^2) dxdy$

[Hint: Proceed as we did for the one-dimensional case and use the divergence theorem to “integrate by parts” ] which I don't understand

Assume now that we take into account friction between air and the membrane; the displacement of the membrane now satisﬁes the damped Wave Equation, which reads:

$u_{tt} - c^2 (u_{xx} + u_{yy}) = -vu_{t}$

with the same boundary conditions. Show that, in this case, energy is always a strictly decreasing function except if $u(x, y, t) = 0$, for which it is constant equal to $0$.
[Hint: What condition must $u_t$ satisfy in order for E to be non-decreasing?
What PDE will u satisfy? Conclude using the maximum principle.

My attempt:

So first I found the derivative of E(t) and if the derivative of E(t) = 0 then I know the energy is conserved and I used integral by parts in 3 dimension to solve that

to get $\iint 2u_{t}u_{tt} = 0$ because it is decreasing. Since the derivative is 0 E is constant over time

therefore the energy is concerved.

But I do not understand the last part please any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: any help? this is really confusing

Answer (score 7):

First part: multiply the equation by $u_t$ and integrate over the area of the membrane. The result is then integrated by parts (explained below)

$$0=\int [u_t u_{tt}-c^2 u_t (u_{xx}+u_{yy})]dx dy=\int [u_t u_{tt}+c^2 (u_{tx}u_{x}+u_{ty}u_{y})]dx dy\\
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\int [u_{t}^2+c^2 (u_{x}^2+u_{y}^2)]dx dy$$

and the energy is conserved. The integration by parts is an application of the divergence theorem in 2D (or Green's theorem). I write it in vector notation:

$$\int \nabla\cdot(u_t\nabla u)dx dy = \int u_t \nabla u\cdot d\mathbf{n}$$

where $d\mathbf{n}$ is a line element directed outwards. The RHS vanishes on account of the boundary conditions.

Second part: repeat with the damped equation and instead find that now

$$\frac{dE}{dt}=-\nu\int u_t^2\, dx dy$$

which is negative.