# Show that energy is decreasing - PDE - Energy

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

$ u_{tt}-u_{t}-u_{xx} =0\;,\;t>0\;,\;x\in(0,\pi)
\\ 
u(0,t)=u(\pi,t)=0,\; t>0
\\
E(t):= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi(u_t^2(x,t)+u_x^2(x,t))dx.
\\
$

I solved this equation and I end up with something like that 
$
E'(t)=\int_0^\pi (u_tu_{tt}+u_xu_{xt})\mathrm dx=\int_0^\pi (u_tu_{xx}+u_xu_{xt})\mathrm dx+\int_0^\pi (u_t)^2\mathrm dx$. 
Since $\int_0^\pi (u_tu_{xx}+u_xu_{xt})\mathrm dx = \int_0^\pi(u_tu_x)_xdx=0$
we ended with $E'(t)=\int_0^\pi (u_t)^2\mathrm dx$. How can I show that   it is decreasing? thanks in advance

Comment: @Winther I did not forget minus, because I used $u_{tt} = u_{xx} {+} u_t$ and multiplied with $u_t$ and got $u_t *u_{tt}=u_t*(u_{xx}+u_t) $ and substituted it to integral.

Comment: It must be a typo in the problem and it's intended that the equation is $u_{tt} \color{red}{+} u_t - u_{xx} = 0$. Your calculation is correct. As the problem is written the energy will in general increase with time.

Comment: The same problem can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513691/proving-energy-conservation-for-wave-equation Notice that the friction term $u_t$ in that case has the opposite sign as you have here.